# Using SIPML5 in guest mode

Tags: asterisk, sipml

I want to setup a **SIPML5** client who can call my server without any authentication. The scenario is that I want my website to call my office without dialing any number or anything.

I've been told I need to enable `allowguest` in my asterisk because if I enable authentication then different website users would race each other or kick each other out since they'll be using the same credentials.

Now my problem is that I can not find the way to use **SIPML5** without giving it authentication info. Does anyone know how to use **SIPML5** in an anonymous way?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
autocreatepeer = yes
```

And use random username at your client side

But note, no authentification is not something you really need to do, becuase of spammers and crackers.

Comment: Do you have any solution other than no authentication? How would you implement calling your office from your website?

Comment: You have generate on your page temporary account and put thoose account into asterisk(via realtime) and sipml5 client(no idea how)